# How to return a list from a function for a "select... IN.." statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wish to write a function for an ERP system that returns a list that can be used in a "select...IN" statement.  For example...

instead of...

"select * from A where b in ('c','d','e')"

I need something like...

"select * from A where b in (get_items('a'))"

I've tried a function that can create the 'c','d','e' bit, but that doesn't give me any results.

I've tried several methods, but I can't seem to hit upon the right idea.  I'm okay with writing API's/functions, but what's the best method to get a list of items out of a function and into that select statement?  would an array or a sys refcursor work?

Comment: how is the function deriving the items to be used in the predicate? I ask because maybe a function is the wrong solution here - maybe a view would be better, if the function is using queries to derive the items.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a function which returns a *table*. Here's an example based on Scott's sample schema. The function accepts department number and returns list of empnos in that deptno.

```
SQL> create or replace function get_emps (par_deptno in number)
  2     return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4     l_list  sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist ();
  5  begin
  6     select empno
  7       bulk collect into l_list
  8       from emp
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10
 11     return l_list;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Code that looks like yours (with `IN`):

```
SQL> select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.empno in (select * from table(get_emps(10)));

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT      10000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
```

Code that uses `JOIN` (the result will be the same):

```
SQL> select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  2  from emp e join table(get_emps(10)) t on e.empno = t.column_value;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT      10000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

SQL>
```